# Add a specified # of record to MSAccess Table Automatically

Tags: sql, ms-access

Happy Holidays. I have two dependent tables, [orders] and [reviews], linked by a "one to many relationship". On the [Orders], the PK is [Order#], there is a column for [#_of_reviews_ordered]. On the [reviews] table (the PK is an auto number) the linked field is [order#] and the number of records (records on the table) should equal "[Orders].[#_of_reviews_ordered]". 
Is there a simple way to accomplish this without having to do add the records to [reviews] manually?

Comment: Not a simple way with Access SQL.  If you're proficient with Access VBA, you can create a procedure using DAO recordsets.  Read information from the `[orders]` recordset and add rows as required to the `[reviews]` recordset.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this without VBA is fairly convoluted and would only work if your number of reviews orders fits within a finite (and reasonably small) range.  For my explanation I will assume # of review will be between 0 and 3

You would need to create a table called, say, TemplateReviews.  This would have at least one field called "KeyNumber", which should not actually be a key.  You could also repeat as many fields as desired from Reviews, and use them to store default values for the rows to be inserted.

The important thing about TemplateReviews is that you must set it up in advance to have N rows with KeyNumber=N for each possible value of KeyNumber.  For my example, we can have 0 to 3 # of reviews.  So TemplateReviews will have:

- 0 rows with KeyNumber=0
- 1 row with KeyNumber=1
- 2 rows with KeyNumber=2
- 3 rows with KeyNumber=3

Once you have TemplateReviews set up, you need to create an Insert query based on it.  The query will insert rows from TemplateReviews into Reviews.  But you also have to filter KeyNumber to match the value on the currently selected Order, as in

```
=Forms!Orders![#_of_reviews]
```

You then need run Insert query to run using a macro triggered by a button (etc) on the Orders form.  This only works the first time you click the button... but you can modify the criteria expression above to subtract the number of existing reviews, as in

```
=Forms!Orders![#_of_reviews] - DCount("*","Reviews","OrderId=" & Forms!Orders![order#])
```

Hope this helps.  If you got this approach working, you could then replace the button with a single line of VBA code in the Order form AfterUpdate event to trigger the insert query.